# Alternative for MFC functions in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, atl

Alternative for MFC AfxIsValidAddress in c++ ?

Comment: Take a look at this http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/afxisvalidaddress-et-al-dont-work-as-advertised/

Comment: I assume you want to use a AfxIsValidAddress equivalent in a non MFC application on the windows platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function actually does not do what it says...

It says that it checks the memory range to see whether it is mapped to the space address of the process. But actually, in most versions of the library, it just checks for a NULL value.

The rationale seems to be that in older versions of Windows, it relied on [IsBadReadPtr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends. But these functions are totally obsolete, and should not be used in newer code (according to MSDN), thus the change in behavior.

That said, if you want to really check for a memory range, your best option is [VirtualQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: [More info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx) on why IsBaXXXPtr shouldn't be used.

Comment: @user786653: It is probably a remnant of the 16-bit era when there was no SEH. I have no more details than those in the linked MSDN. Probably it has something to do with multitasking: relying in that function can easily result in race conditions. And if you have to use SEH anyway for these cases, then this function is not necessary.